# There are n people eligible to vote in a certain election. Voting requires registration. Decisions are made independently. (Blitzstein, Hwang)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is problem 23 chapter 3 from Blitzstein, Introduction to Probability.

> There are $n$ people eligible to vote in a certain election. Voting
> requires registration. Decisions are made independently. Each of the n
> people will register with probability $p_1$. Given that a person
> registers, he or she will vote with probability $p_2$. Given that a
> person votes, he or she will vote for Kodos (who is one of the
> candidates) with probability $p_3$. What is the distribution of the
> number of votes for Kodos (give the PMF, fully simplified, or the name
> of the distribution, including its parameters)?

My attempt which is most likely wrong. Let $X$ be the # of people who voted for Kodos.

$P(X=k) = {n\choose k} (p_1p_2p_3)^k [(1-p_1)^{(n-k)} \:\:+\:\: $
$ \sum_{r=1}^{n-k}{n-k\choose r} ((p_1(1-p_2))^r(1-p_1)^{n-k-r} \:\: +$
$ \sum_{j=1}^{n-k}{n-k\choose j} (p_1p_2(1-p_3))^j (p_1(1-p_2))^{n-k-j}  ]$

Explanation: Let there are k people out of n who voted for Kodos, then those k people, must have registered, voted as well as voted for Kodos so that's ${n\choose k} (p_1p_2p_3)^k$. Then the remaining n-k people could either 1. have not registered at all so that's $(1-p_1)^{(n-k)}$ 2. A subset of r of them have registered but not voted, while remaining $n-k-r$ haven't registered at all, which makes $ \sum_{r=1}^{n-k}{n-k\choose r} ((p_1(1-p_2))^r(1-p_1)^{n-k-r}$ 3. A subset of j of them have registered, voted but not voted for Kodos while remaining $n-k-j$ have registered but not voted so that's $ \sum_{j=1}^{n-k}{n-k\choose j} (p_1p_2(1-p_3))^j (p_1(1-p_2))^{n-k-j}$

I not only think this is a wrong answer, I also don't like this approach. I am looking for correct solution and better approaches to this problem. For example: If I define 3 random variables
as # of people who registered, # of people who voted, # of people who voted for Kodos, these 3 have binomial distributions. But I don't know how to proceed using this approach. Thanks.

Comment: For each people there are only two outcomes; vote for Kodos or not whatever the reason is. So it's a binomial distribution with $p=p_{1}\cdot p_{2}\cdot p_{3}$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I don't get it. If they don't vote for Kodos, there are many ways to do that not just $1-p_1p_2p_3$. Can you explain that part?

Comment: $\left(1-p_{1}\right)+p_{1}\left(1-p_{2}\right)+p_{1}p_{2}\left(1-p_{3}\right)=1-p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}$. If the probability of voting for Kodos is $p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}$ then the probability of not voting for him must be $1-p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}$. The reason we use complement is because we don't want to count all the probability one by one.